# What is the name of this interval operation?

Tags: interval-arithmetic, discrete-time

I have encountered an basic operation on a set of intervals which I think should have a common name and be in textbooks. Unfortunately, my searches have turned up empty.

Imagine you have a set of intervals $I$. From this set, you want to calculate a partitioning $P$. Namely, you want to find the set of disjoint intervals which partitions $I$ into sub-intervals such that for each interval $p$ in $P$, all points contained in $p$ overlap with the same intervals in $I$.

[image: Picture as a link (as I'm not yet allowed to include pictures)]

The closest I’ve found which resembles this kind of operation is the “sectioned” operation of an R package called [IntervalSurgeon](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/IntervalSurgeon/vignettes/intro.html).

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I’ve encountered this problem in the context of a master thesis about the analysis of timed systems. The context is that the intervals represent time ranges during which the system displays a certain behaviour while the partitions are time ranges for which you know that for all points of time inside that time range the systems displays the same behaviour .

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I fixed the notation.

Comment: Is it perhaps the set of *atoms* of the Boolean algebra generated by $I$?

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @HansvanderLaan Sadly I've never really studied this stuff, so I probably couldn't present the context properly. You're better off asking Google about atoms of a Boolean algebra than me! Hopefully someone else will chime in.